# Do ManagedScheduledExecutorService tasks survive server restart or crash?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, scheduledexecutorservice

I noticed on my development environment (Netbeans and Glassfish) that scheduled tasks created by `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` do not survive a server restart.

Am I doing something wrong or is this meant to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

If the JVM shuts down due to a server restart/crash then the tasks are gone, too. That's how it should work. 
You would need to find a way to permanently store the information and recreate the tasks on startup.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the Timer Service instead of the Executor Service, but in this case I'm not sure if it is possible to start multiple worker threads. I've read that the Timer Service tasks are all scheduled on a single thread. Or is it possible to have a thread pool also for the Timer Service?

Comment: that would be a different question. those will be gone after a server restart too though.

Comment: Sorry if I have to correct you, that's not true. They do survive a restart, but not a redeployment. Taken from the Java EE Tutorial: `Timers are persistent by default. If the server is shut down or crashes, persistent timers are saved and will become active again when the server is restarted. If a persistent timer expires while the server is down, the container will call the @Timeout method when the server is restarted.`

Comment: hmm, ok. they are saved and loaded back after reboot.